# HttpPost + setEntity : how to know content-length?

Tags: android, entity, http-post, content-length

I've set almost all my data :

```
String capcha = editText.getText().toString();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.asp");

// Add your data                    
String str = "param1=x&param2=y";
StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(str);
httppost.setEntity(strEntity);

httppost.setHeader("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", ); HOW TO GET CONTENT LENGTH ?

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Waqas the question of the link refers to `HttpUrlConnection` which I'm not using. How can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this may help to solve your problem:

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(strEntity.getContentLength()));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `InputStreamEntity` as by default it takes a length of `-1`.